# Reducing array to string avoiding foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array to reduce to string, but I've to do **MANY** times so I would like to use some array PHP function (some combination of array_walk, array_reduce,...) but none fit my needs, but I belive there's a solution that I miss. The code have to be PHP5.6 compliant too.

```
$list =[
    'k1' => 'vA1 vA2 vA2',
    'k2' => 'vB1 vB2 vB2',
    'k3' => '',
    'k4' => 'vC1 vC2 vC2',
    'k5' => NULL,
    'k6' => 'vD1 vD2 vD2',
];

function reduce($list){
    $_buff="";
    $_sep="";
    foreach ($list as $k => $v){
        if($v===null){
            continue;
        }
        $_buff.="$_sep$k $v";
        $_sep="; ";
    }
    return $_buff;
}

echo reduce($list)."\n";
```

The expected result is

> ```
> k1 vA1 vA2 vA2; k2 vB1 vB2 vB2; k3 ; k4 vC1 vC2 vC2; k6 vD1 vD2 vD2
> ```

Please note the different behavior if value is an empty string or *null*.

Comment: Can you explain  the question like what do you want. As your codes gives you the output you need. So what is the issue??

Comment: You could try using `print_r($arr,true)` and then apply one or more `preg_replace()` calls with a suitable regexp on the returned string to get your desired output.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI my goal is the efficency

Comment: @cars10 I don't think preg_replace() will be more efficent than foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think there will be significant execution time difference with foreach or any array_* function. It will matter only if records increase more than 100K I guess.

```
$result = array();

array_walk($list, function($value, $key) use (&$result) {
    if($value!==null) {
        $result[] = $key .' '. $value;
    }
});

print_r(implode('; ', $result));
```

Why don't you compare the time taken from all answer and choose the best one ;)

Comment: "k3" should be stay

Comment: trim($value) and !== null should do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) like:

```
$list = [
    'k1' => 'vA1 vA2 vA2',
    'k2' => 'vB1 vB2 vB2',
    'k3' => '',
    'k4' => 'vC1 vC2 vC2',
    'k5' => NULL,
    'k6' => 'vD1 vD2 vD2',
];

$list = array_filter($list, function ($value) {
    return $value !== null;
});

$array = array_map(function ($key, $value) {
    return trim($key . ' ' . $value);
}, array_keys($list), $list);

echo implode('; ', $array);
```

The result is:

> k1 vA1 vA2 vA2; k2 vB1 vB2 vB2; k3; k4 vC1 vC2 vC2; k6 vD1 vD2 vD2

Comment: unfortunately "k5" should not be returned

Comment: @IvanButtinoni Though this does avoid using `foreach`, I'm pretty sure it is going to be less efficient. The whole list is iterated twice by `array_map()` and `implode()` when you can do this with one iteration using a `foreach` solution.

Comment: @kunruh I got your point, but despite what our guts say lets do some profiler

Answer (score 1):

This's not an answer but some thoughts and data about the question and the answers.

My goal is to avoid `foreach` because It's slow.

In a really surprising way, my implementation is the quickest!

As pointed out by @kunruh `foreach` is quicker than collection of functions **and allocating memory for intermediate values**

The code under profiler:

```
<?php

function filterNull($v) {
    if ($v === null) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

class ProfileSolution
{
    const LOOP_LV1 = 200;
    const LOOP_LV2 = 300;
    public function reduceIvan($list){
        $_buff="";
        $_sep="";
        foreach ($list as $k => $v){
            if($v===null){
                continue;
            }
            $_buff.="$_sep$k $v";
            $_sep="; ";
        }
        return $_buff;
    }
    public function reduceMateiMihai ($list)
    {
        $_list = array_filter($list, function ($value) {
            return $value !== null;
        });

        $array = array_map(function ($key, $value) {
            return trim($key . ' ' . $value);
        }, array_keys($_list), $_list);

        return implode('; ', $array);
    }
    public function reduceMasterFly($list){
        $array = [];
        foreach( $list as $key => $value ){
            $tmp = [];
            if ( !is_null($value) ){
                $tmp[] = $key;
                $tmp[] = $value;
                $array[] = implode(" ", $tmp);
            }
        }
        return implode("; ", $array);
    }
    public function reduceKunruh($list) {
        $result = "";
        foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
            if ($value === NULL) continue;

            $result .= " $key $value;";
        }

        // remove trailing semicolon
        $result = substr($result, 0, -1);

        return $result;
    }
    public function reduceHmmm ($list)
    {
        $result = array();

        array_walk($list, function($value, $key) use (&$result) {
            if($value!==null) {
                $result[] = $key .' '. $value;
            }
        });

        return print_r(implode('; ', $result),true);
    }
    public function reduceAd ($list)
    {
        $filteredList = array_filter($list, 'filterNull');
        return implode("; ", array_map(function($k, $v){
            return "$k $v";
        }, array_keys($filteredList), array_values($filteredList)));
    }

    public function testReduceIvan ($list)
    {
        $t=0;
        while($t++ < self::LOOP_LV2){
            $res="";
            $res=$this->reduceIvan($list);
        }
    }
    public function testReduceMateiMihai ($list)
    {
        $t=0;
        while($t++ < self::LOOP_LV2){
            $res="";
            $res=$this->reduceMateiMihai($list);
        }
    }
    public function testReduceMasterFly ($list)
    {
        $t=0;
        while($t++ < self::LOOP_LV2){
            $res="";
            $res=$this->reduceMasterFly($list);
        }
    }
    public function testReduceKunruh ($list)
    {
        $t=0;
        while($t++ < self::LOOP_LV2){
            $res="";
            $res=$this->reduceKunruh($list);
        }
    }
    public function testReduceHmmm ($list)
    {
        $t=0;
        while($t++ < self::LOOP_LV2){
            $res="";
            $res=$this->reduceHmmm($list);
        }
    }
    public function testReduceAD ($list)
    {
        $t=0;
        while($t++ < self::LOOP_LV2){
            $res="";
            $res=$this->reduceAD($list);
        }
    }


    public function run ()
    {
        $list =[
            'k1'    => 'magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque',
            'k2'    => 'porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem',
            'k3'    => '',
            'k4'    => 'minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem',
            'k5'    => NULL,
            'k6'  => 'non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt  labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis',
            'k7'  => 'aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur',
            'k8'  => 'sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae',
            'k9'  => 'vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam',
            'k10' => 'nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam',
            'k11' => 'inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor',
            'k12' => 'amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia',
            'k13' => Null,
            'k14' => 'pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and',
            'k15' => 'explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes',
            'k16' => 'amet, consectetur, adipisci velit,  quia',
            'k17' => 'or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter',
            'k18' => 'consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain',
            'k19' => 'voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque',
            'k20' => Null,
            'k21' => 'inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit ',
            'k22' => 'amet, consectetur,  velit, sed quia',
            'k23' => 'laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas',
            'k24'  => 'non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis',
        ];

        $t=0;
        while($t++ < self::LOOP_LV1){
            $this->testReduceIvan($list);
            $this->testReduceMateiMihai($list);
            $this->testReduceMasterFly($list);
            $this->testReduceKunruh($list);
            $this->testReduceHmmm($list);
            $this->testReduceAD($list);
        }



    }

}

$o = new ProfileSolution();
$o->run();
```

Call tree with demo (see the question) data
[image: Call tree with demo (see the question) data]

Call tree with realistic amount of data
[image: Call tree with realistic amount of data]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function reduce($list){
    $array = [];
    foreach( $list as $key => $value ){
        $tmp = [];
        if ( !is_null($value) ){
            $tmp[] = $key;
            $tmp[] = $value;
            $array[] = implode(" ", $tmp);
        }
    }
    return implode("; ", $array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a pretty clean, simple solution:

```
function reduce($list) {
    $result = "";
    foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        if ($value === NULL) continue;

        $result .= " $key $value;";
    }

    // remove trailing semicolon
    $result = substr($result, 0, -1);

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use [array_values](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php), [array_keys](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), [array_map](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), [array_filter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [implode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
function filterNull($v) {
    if ($v === null) {
        return false;
    }   
    return true;
}

$filteredList = array_filter($list, 'filterNull');
echo implode("; ", array_map(function($k, $v){
    return "$k $v";
}, array_keys($filteredList), array_values($filteredList)));
```

array_filter will remove the empty values.
array_keys will retrieve the keys.
array_values will retrieve the values.
array_map will process each cell.
implode will glue each cell of the array together.

Edit: I've changed the whole code since I've misread the first time. Now, the solution is compliant with your needs.

Comment: In expected output the key is included.. but by this method only value gets connected and returned